# Java parameter to load class from non internal path

Tags: java, ibm-was

I need the class DocumentImpl, which is available in *xercesImpl.jar* via path `org/apache/xerces/dom/DocumentImpl`. 
But my code fails because of missing `com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom/DocumentImpl`.
If I add *jaxp-ri.jar* to the classpath it works, but I don't want to use *jaxp-ri.jar*, if I already have the class.

From the classloading policy, my xercesImpl.jar is loaded first. 
Is there a way to tell my code to use the path `org/apache/xerces/dom/` instead of `com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom/`? Via JVM args?

Why is the second path used anyway?

I am running my servlet on a websphere application server.
Thank you

**Edit:** 
Here is my trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:833)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:746)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:665)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.<init>(SOAPPartImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.<init>(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:68)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl.getSOAPPart(Message1_1Impl.java:88)
    at myclass.CreateMessage(myclass.java:1337)
```

**Edit2:**
I use non Oracle-JVM.
I also added these JVM Parameters:

```
-Dorg.xml.sax.parser=org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
-Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl
-Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl
```

Comment: Who calls DocumentImpl, which lib are you using? without knowing these detaisl we cant help.. am afraid..

Comment: I suspect you are having trouble with a non-Oracle JVM (IBM J9?). Try setting the DocumentBuilderFactory (see Q14 https://jaxp.java.net/1.4/JAXP-FAQ.html)

Comment: Yes, non Oracle-JVM. I tried to set it via: -Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl    but this was not sufficient.

Comment: Which WebSphere version and JDK version are you using? Did you try to remove `xercesImpl.jar` from your application?

Comment: JDK 1.6, WAS8. I want to use xercesImpl.jar.

Comment: WAS 8.0 already provides Xerces libraries in the runtime (xml.jar) and other xml related libs. And it provides it in the org/apache/xerces/dom/DocumentImpl package.  Any reason why you want to use external one? You are probably also attaching some other xml related libraries in you app, which refers to the com.sun packages.

Answer (score 0):

I would try referencing the class via its complete path explicitly in the code.

It could be as trivial as your IDE resolving the undesired import automatically.

```
org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl myVariable;
```